# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Здравствуйте.

Laravel 5

При старте приложеия в браузере выдает следующую ошибку, что нет доступа к БД.

Логин и пароль верны, т.к. я под ними зашел в консоль mysql со след коммандой: `mysql -u root -p`

> 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `areas` where `area_type` = 0)' in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:770

Не поимаю почему нет доступа? Если имееет значение, приложение находится на удаленном сервере, это не локалхост.

В .Env указал данные для подключения к БД:

```
PP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jkSYertretVUuiJJr7k+TzJretreUExhJ/Mdr4i3Jg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=frefrefaxc

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_ID=
```

**database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

> Логин и пароль верны, т.к. я под ними зашел в консоль mysql со след
>   коммандой: `mysql -u root -p`

Cудя по команде, вы зашли пользователем `root` а не `user`

Comment: нет это я просто скопировал быстро. а вообще заходил mysql -u user -p

Comment: Ну началось - "ой, это я не так скопировал, не так написал и вообще код из другого окошка". И все это при том, что сообщение об ошибке и так яснее некуда, и задавать после него вопросы смысла не имеет.

Comment: спасибо. оказывается нужно было почистить кэш. и теперь переменные окружения обновились.

Answer (score 1):

После изменения значений переменных окружения в .env необходимо было почистить кэш и все стало на свои места:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```